# Execute a stored procedure from a windows form asynchronously and then disconnect?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, asynchronous

I am calling a stored procedure from my application that can take 30 minutes to execute.

I don't want to make my user leave the application open for that entire time period. So I would like to call the sproc, let it fly, and let them shut down the application and come back later.

How can I do this?

Comment: Well, I am not going to log in or register (sort of disappointed that I can't vote or close this out without doing that). Anyway, Scott W. gave the best answer and then got backed up by a few supporting posts. All accept for the "...buy faster hardware" bit. I'd just assume claim failure, than tell my client they need to buy faster hardware, because I can't get it done right. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Dan - I'm confused.  You're already logged in, at least enough to have a user account and 2 badges.  Why aren't you able to click the accept answer button?

Comment: See also ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444215/how-to-execute-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-asynchronously-and-ensure-its-comp

Answer (score 29):

This is actually a quite common scenario. You cannot do anything client based because the client may go away and disconnect and you'll lose the work achieved so far. The solution is to use [**Service Broker Activation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171617.aspx): you create a service in the database and attach an activated procedure. In your application (or ASP page) you send a message to the service and embed the necessary parameters for your procedure. After your application commits, the message activates the service procedure. the service procedure reads the parameters from the message and invokes your procedure. since activation happens on a server thread unrelated to your original connection, this is reliable. In fact the server can even shutdown and restart *while* your procedure is being executed and the work will be rolled back then resumed, since the activating message will trigger again the service procedure after the restart.

**Update**

I have published the details of how to do this including sample code on my blog: [Asynchronous procedure execution](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/).

Comment: Yes! Thanks very much. One thing to make sure of: The service broker needs to be enabled for the database. (Database Properties -> Options in SSMS) or ALTER DATABASE ... SET ENABLE_BROKER. The nice thing is this even works in Express Editions of SQL Server!

Comment: @Remus Rusanu, i have tried the code from your article (seems comments are disabled there) and came across a weird behaviour. If i write a stored proc to INSERT INTO a table in my db and then WAITFOR some then running it through the ups_AsyncExecInvoke i get my whole table blocked while the proc executes (e.g. i can no longer do SELECT on that table); if i run the same proc directly (without the Broker message) the table doesnt block. Any ideas?

Comment: @zaitsman: There isn't anything specific to activation that should change the behavior. But [activated procedures execute under session settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171585(v=sql.105).aspx) that may differ from a user session because client drivers do set some settings on their own. These differences can result in a different execution plan, one that can use different locking strategy. You will have to investigate what happens. If you have a consistent repro, ask a new question here, post the repro code, and I'll have a look.

Comment: @RemusRusanu, never mind, i missed the BEGIN Transaction in your blog post; since the whole stored proc was part of that, the table was being locked during the execution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`BeginExecuteXXX`/`EndExecuteXXX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutenonquery.aspx) methods (depending whether it returns a result or not) of the `SqlCommand`, passing a callback delegate.

Comment: I don't know why people down-vote without explaining why. This is a perfectly valid answer if they wanted to execute the procedure without fully shutting down the program.

Comment: I can guess the reason: the ThreadPool thread used for BeginXXX will gets aborted when the main thread exists. However, I assumed the OP wants to keep the app open in the background rather than completely shutting down the process (which I think is a valid assumption.)

Comment: I didn't mean to down-vote if I did that (new to this forum, so I may have clicked on accident and didn't realize what I was doing).  I agree, perfectly good solution...but alas, I do want to let them completely kill the app.  Thx Mehrdad.

Comment: Well, I guess it defintely wasn't me...I just tried to vote and I would have to log in to do so (and I'm not).  Anyway, it was helpful.

Comment: You can't have any sort of *reliable* async execution based on BeginExecute for long running tasks. The client process has to stay around, maintaining an open connection, until the execution finishes. The async execution of SqlClient is geared toward scalable, nonblocking, execution of normal database access, not toward launching long running querries.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean from "reliability" here. If I want to submit jobs to SQL server to reliably perform without expecting any results, I'd go with something like MSMQ or service broker but there are plenty of cases where you actually expect a result (e.g. generating a long running report) that you do want to perform in the background where Begin/End methods make perfect sense.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a re-architecture.  Create a "work queue" table where you log requests to run the stored procedure.  Then either have a Windows Service or a SQL Server job check that work queue from time to time (or be really ingenious and use a trigger) to kick off the stored procedure.  Have the stored procedure update the progress from time to time in the work queue table, and your front-end can look at that an tell the user the progress, and then display the results when they're done.

Comment: Well, I am not going to log in or register (sort of disappointed that I can't vote or close this out without doing that).  Anyway, this was the best answer for me and then got backed up by a few supporting posts.  All accept for the "...buy faster hardware" bit.  I'd just assume claim failure, than tell my client they need to buy faster hardware, because I can't get it done right.  

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Dan - the "buy faster hardware" was just kidding.  I'll edit it to remove it.  But faster hardware is sometimes an option.  You're not going to find hardware that's 30 times faster though! ;)

Comment: @Scot, you are basically describing a built in feature: Service Broker Activation. Both Internal and External activation are arguably better than a windows service or an Agent job checking from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to close down your application completely, I suggest you define a job in SQL Server Agent, and just execute a T-SQL statement to start that job manually. The syntax is:

```
sp_start_job 
     {   [@job_name =] 'job_name'
       | [@job_id =] job_id }
     [ , [@error_flag =] error_flag]
     [ , [@server_name =] 'server_name']
     [ , [@step_name =] 'step_name']
     [ , [@output_flag =] output_flag]
```

The job would execute your stored procedure. You will have to be a little creative to pass in any arguments. For example, insert the parameters into a "queue" table and have the job process all the rows in the queue.

Instead of a job, an insert trigger on your queue should work as well.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use a background service for offline processing, where your user app tells the service what to do and then disconnects. The service can log elapsed times and errors/status, and restart if necessary. WCF is designed for this and supports queues to communicate with.

Comment: Remus had a good answer, and I appreciate him taking the time to post the blog article. That would be much less work than creating a separate background service if it's applicable to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

> let them shut down the app and come
>   back later

If you're going to allow them to *completely* close the app, you'll have to start up a seperate .exe or something in a different ThreadPool that executes your code calling the stored procedure. Otherwise your thread will die when you close the app.

Comment: I agree, if you want your application to be able to close you'll need to completely move the sproc call out of the original process.

Answer (score 1):

Another method that you could do would be to allow your application to run in the background (possibly in the notification area) and then exit or notify when the job completes. You could use this by using the BeginExecuteNonQuery and EndExecuteNonQuery methods to allow it to run in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your application's main window does not need to be open. If you launched it as a secondary thread, it will continue to run so long as `IsBackground == false`. I usually prefer to do this stuff through SQL Server Agent or as a client-server application (nothing prevents a client-server app from both running on the same machine, or even being the same binary).

It's been a while...

```
using System.Threading;

.....

Thread _t = null;
void StartProcedure()
{
  _t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.StartProc));
  _t.IsBackground = false;//If I remember correctly, this is the default value. 
  _t.Start();
}

bool ProcedureIsRunning
{
 get { return _t.IsRunning; } //Maybe it's IsActive. Can't remember. 
}

void StartProc(object param)
{
  //your logic here.. could also do this as an anonymous method. Broke it out to keep it simple. 
}
```