# How to execute a sql server stored procedure asynchronously and ensure it's completion

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that when called does a large amount of processing.  Various parts of the stored procedure are wrapped in their own transactions but, the entire proc. does not run in a transaction as this would cause unnecessary blocking and harm performance.  The problem I have is that if a user closes the user interface after the proc. has started and before it ends, the connection closes and the proc. stops executing.

Is there any way to do this asynchronously or in another process that won't abort if the user interface application is closed during processing.

Comment: Will you ever need more than one instance of the stored procedure running concurrently? What edition of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Andres - That's version not edition and you still didn't answer my other question. Reason for asking both is to see whether SQL Agent Job (not available in express) might be an option.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229438/execute-a-stored-procedure-from-a-windows-form-asynchronously-and-then-disconnect

Comment: I am using the Express edition and the procedure must be able to run concurrently

Comment: Ah OK For a SQL Server solution service broker as per @Dmitry's link is definitely the way forward then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the C# Task Parallel Library.
You can create a task which is very simple. For example...

```
    Task myTask= new Task(() => {
        Console.WriteLine(@"hello");
        //Call stored procedure here
    });
    myTask.start();
```

This will run the code wrapped in the task in parallel with the main thread. If you wish to check the task is complete you can use

```
    if(myTask.IsCompleted())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"My task is finished");
    }
```

This method avoided altering the stored procedure and allows C# to handle the performance.

Edit:-
And to avoid the main thread finishing first add

```
    Task.WaitAll(myTask);
```

This will sleep the main thread until the task is complete.

Comment: what will happen to the task if the main applicaiton process is ended before the task completes?

Comment: @Andrew - I have updated my solution to show how this is resolved.

Comment: thanks I had a play around and this does sort of work.  I need a solution that is resilient to a power down etc.

Comment: What would you like to happen in the event of a power down? I don't fully understand what you mean by that...

Comment: As the sp is long running I want to make sure it completes even if the ui that triggers the call to the sp is closed or the computer has a power failure.  I am now looking at either wcf or maybe nservicebus.  A service on the server can run the sp.  Note the computers are tablet devices that can easily get powered down during the processing

Comment: If you want something durable, look into SQL Service Broker - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Call SP_Start_Job to initialise the stored procedure. Modify the stored procedure to write a completion flag to a table. Poll the table on a thread in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of doing this:

1. You can build a c# service that executes the stored procedure in a separate thread. The GUI would only be responsible for telling the service to start the procedure and to ask if the task was done. The GUI can close and re-open and the service would still be up and running.
2. Running a SQL Server agent job. Start the job from the GUI and check regularly if it has completed.

If you only have this only sp that you need to make sure finishes I'd go with second option. I've tried Integration Services as "service" way back but it was way to hungry for running the number of processes we need to run asynchrnously... ran out of memory constantly.