# Asynchronous stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, asynchronous

Given the following two SQL Server 2005 stored procedures (samples only):

**ProcA:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcA]
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC ProcB
END
```

**ProcB:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcB]
AS
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '000:00:10'
END
```

When `ProcA` is executed, it predictably takes 10 seconds since it is waiting for `ProcB` to complete.

Is it possible to have `ProcA` call `ProcB` **asynchronously**, so that `ProcA` returns as soon as it has called `ProcB` and does not wait for `ProcB` to complete before returning?

Comment: Perhaps [this (click link)](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/) might work for you?

Comment: Use service broker or put ProcB in a job and call it using sp_start_job.

Comment: @tozka: Introducing Service Broker is not a step you should take lightly.  It's a complex queueing system with non-zero maintenance requirements and costs.

Comment: @tozka: That link looks like **way** too much work for such a simple problem. But I'll resort to that if there's no better way. @ aaron: that's a good idea. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1230171/1324019) and [subsequent blog post](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution) which I ended up using to make my stored procedures run asynchronously.