# Long-running stored procedure out of IIS process

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis, stored-procedures

I have a long running stored procedure that imports lots of records from an old system and takes hours to execute. While executing maybe the IIS process needs recycling or web server needs restart or something else that caused the IIS process to end and accordingly aborted the execution of the stored procedure.

I've decided to run the stored procedure out of w3wp.exe process, in a disconnected environment.

Solutions:

- Service Broker Activation:I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229438/execute-a-stored-procedure-from-a-windows-form-asynchronously-and-then-disconnect) but it's complex and [diagnosting service queue is difficult](http://rusanu.com/2007/10/31/error-handling-in-service-broker-procedures/)
- Run under a Windows Service:
- Define a SQL Server Job: it needs SQLAgentReaderRole role permission and I need pass parameters to the stored procedures

Is there any other solution?

Comment: What about a console app that you call from the web app?. This is a very simple solution, you can pass parameters and it can run for hours

Comment: Windows Service is better than Console App, but both of them doesn't run automatically while restarting server. service broker solution support this.

Comment: I've used https://www.hangfire.io/ and it works well for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer the Windows Service route. Lately I've used [self-hosted WebApi](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/web-api-self-hosting-using-windows-service/) which allows me to start a long running job from MVC (using HttpClient or System.Net.HttpWebRequest, etc).

Comment: It also needs call again sp if restart web server and also register windows service. i think best practice is first solution, Sql Service Broker

Comment: And also windows service consume resource even it does nothing.

Comment: Those are valid points. I wouldn't use a service for this one single purpose,  only if it's doing other things as well so the resource consumption can be justified. But a service can easily handle executing your sp on restart.

Answer (score 0):

> CLR Assembly.

change your code as a class library, and import dll result of class library as an assembly function of SSMS, with this Code

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY myAssembly from 'E:\Projects\CL.dll'
```

now you can call it without any concern of IIS stop.

Comment: It also needs call again sp if restart web server. i think best practice is first solution, Sql Service Broker

Comment: I asked about store procedure, not .net code. also i prefer working with pure sql server features and abilities instead of CLR assembly because it's more maintainable, and i'm not sure about CLR assembly performance