# Asynchronous SQL procedure execution set and wait for completion

Tags: t-sql, asynchronous, sql-server-2016, service-broker

Say I have a large set of calls to a procedure to run which have varying parameters but are independent so I want to make parallel/async calls. I use the service broker to fire these all off but the problem I have is I want to know neat ways of knowing how to wait for them all to complete (or error).

Is there a way to do this? I believe I could just loop with waits on the result table checking for completion on that but that isn't very "event triggered". Hoping for a nicer way to do this.

I have used the service broker with queue code and processing based off this other answer: [Remus' service broker queuing example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1230171/1519839)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day Shiv,

There are several ways (like always) that you can use in order to implement this requirement. One of these is using this logic:

(1) Create two queues: one will be the trigger to execute the main SP that you want execute in Asynchronous, and the other will be the trigger to execute whatever you want to execute after all the executions ended.

(2) When you create the message in the first queue you should also create a message in the second queue, which will only tell us which execution did not ended yet (first queue gives the information which execution started since once we START the execution we use the message and remove it from the queue).

(3) Inside the SP that you execute using the main first queue (this part executed in synchronous):

(3.1) execute the queries you need

(3.2) clear the equivalent message from the second queue (meaning that this message will removed only after the queries ended)

(3.3) check if there are messages in the second queue. If there are no messages then all the tasks ended and you can execute your final step

** Theoretically instead of using the second queue, you can store data in a table, but using second queue should probably give better performance then updating table each time an execution ended. Anyhow, you test the option of using a table as well.

Comment: > (3.3) check if there are messages in the second queue. If there are no messages then all the tasks ended and you can execute your final step
When you say this, this is the core of my question - the mechanism you use for this check?

Comment: In the logic above, you check the second queue inside the same stored procedure (SP) that is triggered by the first main queue. It is part of the transaction that include your main query (this is why steps 3.1 - 3.3 is not a new step but part of step 3). I assumed from your description that you know how to work with queue and messages since you describe that you know how to use service broker to execute your queries asynchronous. Do you mean that you do not know how to check if the queue is empty or the logic is not clear to you yet?

Comment: I think I understand what the workflow is. (3.3) sounds like a potential race condition - if say the final two queued items complete at the same time, it would be possible to process the "final step" multiple times?

Comment: The other issue I have is that I want the main thread to continue rather than continuing main script execution from the second queue processor.

Comment: Regarding the first point, this is something you should cover in the final step. For example if in the final step you create table then first check if the table exists. You did not provide us any real information but only stories, which lead to general theory discussion only! If you want specific solution then we need to reproduce the relevant scenario, meaning you need to provide queries to create all the relevant elements (tables, insert sample data, current services broker,  MESSAGE type, CONTRACT, and so on.... It seems like you got the theory answer and you understood the steps

Comment: Regarding the second comment  `continue rather than continuing...`, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Actually, since you can only RECEIVE a message once, you an add a check before you remove the message if Queue is empty and if it is then you do not need to go to step 3.2 and 3.3. In this way you do not have an option of duplicate  final step (you cannot RECEIVE the same message twice/multiple times).